# Laravel caching items still hitting the database

Tags: php, database, laravel, caching

this code is not caching the items.

its getting into the condition but still hitting the database.
what could be wrong?

the items are saved in redis. and I can access it

> get laravel:stores_ar_19_36_80_93

My Controller looks like this.

```
class StoresController extends Controller
  {
    public function get(Request $request)
     {
          if (\Cache::has($key)) {
              \Log::info('cache hit on stores');
               return \Cache::get($key);
           }
        return Store::with('openingHours', 'currency', 'storeTags.tag')->find($areaStore);
     }
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I'm using the waavi translation package and apparently something is getting messed up with that. it's not a caching problem.

Comment: what cache driver are you using?

Comment: I tried with both `redis` and `file`. but both didnt work

Comment: your problem is not clear. you are saying it is getting into the condition and also hitting the database which means you are getting the data, where is the problem then ?

Comment: I dont want it to hit the database if I want to return from the cache.

Comment: if u return from cache then laravel do not get data from database .. i think u missing in configuration ... if you are using redis then login into redis-server and  check redis cache a data or not ..

Comment: You need to post more code. The mistake is somewhere else. Perhaps you are using route binding? There is no way we can replicate your setup with just the code you have given, so there is no way we can help you.